# Implement the progressing bar reading a csv file alive_progress

Tags: python, pandas, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a progressing bar into my code while it reads my csv file (and I would like to implement it to the others functions too).

However, I am not sure how to implement this code to my reading code, because it stays progressing, and it never ends

```
import pandas as pd
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time

with alive_bar(100, theme='ascii') as bar:

    file = pd.read_csv('file.csv', 
                        sep = ';', 
                        skiprows = 56,
                        parse_dates = [['Date','Time']])
    bar()
```

And, what happens if I would like to apply a progressing bar to a for loop?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need to call `bar()` every time you want to update the progress bar by 1. So if your `total` is 100 you would have to call `bar()` 100 times. In your example you are reading csv file and it is only 1 operation, so the progress bar will be updated only by 1. You can read csv file by chunks and for each chunk call `bar()` to update the progress bar. `total` would be the number of chunks. Here is how to read in chunks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to parse the file in chunks and get the number of lines beforehand to calculate the total number of chunks:

```py
import pandas as pd
from alive_progress import alive_bar

filepath = "file.csv"

num_lines = sum(1 for _ in open(filepath, 'r'))
chunksize = 5000

reader = pd.read_csv(filepath, chunksize=chunksize)

with alive_bar(int(num_lines/chunksize)) as bar:
    for chunk in reader:
        process_chunk()
        bar()
```

The row counting wastes a lot of time of course, so I'd only recommend this if the processing takes much longer than the reading itself and you absolutely have to have a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add a progress bar to this?

In general with progress bars you need some way of adding a hook to the actual read loop.  In this case I would simply not bother: if you're going to use a high-level library like pandas, presumably it's because you *don't* want to manage the whole reading-parsing loop yourself.

> How do I use a for loop?

This is much easier.  From the docs:

```
from alive_progress import alive_it

for item in alive_it(items):   # <<-- wrapped items
    print(item)                # process each item
```

> Why doesn't my bar update?

Because you only call `bar()` once, which is the function which updates the bar.  `alive_progress` isn't magic: if you tell it you will need `100` iterations it expects you to call `bar()` 100 times.  It will move the bar 1/100th forward every time, and from the time between calls to `bar()` it will calculate how fast you are going and how long you likely have to wait.